# METEOR: How to revert "sudo chown -Rh <username> .meteor/local"

Tags: meteor

While trying to get meteor build to work, I was prompted to run this line

```
"sudo chown -Rh <username> .meteor/local"
```

by my terminal. I gave it a try, but now mup deploy doesnt work anymore which it did before. How do I revert the command?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the owner of the `.meteor/local` before you've run it?

Comment: no idea, should be the default owner, I am guessing root because Meteor needs root for a lot of things to work

Comment: Could you just run `ls -la` and copy and paste whole line with `.meteor` in it here.

Comment: drwxrwxr-x  3 jan jan 4096 Jan 24 20:58 .meteor

Answer (score 1):

It happens when you installed meteor as another user. For this scenario, I think you installed it while logged in as "root". You can try the ff:

- use mup with sudo
- verify who owns .meteor/local directory.

Let me know if this works. Thanks

Comment: it says 0755/drwxr-xr-x is the owner (Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x))

Comment: the Uid is root and the Gid is my user account, if that helps :)

Comment: Wait, so what if I just delete and reinstall meteor?

Comment: you could just remove the existing directory and reinstall.